# Can we override ENV method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Normal behaviour

`ENV[SOME_ENV_VARIABLE]` points to `.env` file or ENVIRONMENT var for heroku

Custom behaviour

I want if someone is calling `ENV[SOME_ENV_VARIABLE]` I want to trigger a method with argument `SOME_ENV_VARIABLE`. and that method should return somevalue if that value is `nil` then it should return that value from .env file

```
`ENV[SOME_ENV_VARIABLE]` # a method call to delegate_env_var(key) where key = SOME_ENV_VARIABLE


 def delegate_env_var(key) # key is `SOME_ENV_VARIABLE`
   value = databasecall(key)
   value.nil? ? ENV[SOME_ENV_VARIABLE] : value
 end
```

Comment: `databasecall(key).nil? ? databasecall(key) : ENV[key]` can be better to be called instead of playing with default implementation. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

`ENV` is not a method, but a constant:

```
> defined? ENV
=> "constant"
```

You can reassign it to whatever object you want, even to a string (accepting the warning):

```
ENV = "asd"
(pry):27: warning: already initialized constant ENV
=> "asd"
```

So you could probably create an object that would implement `[]` method in a way you described and delegate other ones to `ENV`.

It's quite risky though. I'd rather add a custom class that wraps `ENV` and access environment vars through that class:

class Env
     def self.get
       # get from DB or ENV
     end
   end

Comment: How can I get arguments passed to `[ ]` methods i.e `Env['argument']`